# Unbind/unsynchronized scrolling in source control compare function

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019, source-control-explorer

In compare option inside the source control, the scrolling is bind together for both files.

I want to scroll just one of the sides while the other stay pinned also I want to avoid comparing outside on the VS.
I can't find any solution online and there is no obvious option in the VS.

I'm Using VS2015 with TFS.

Thank you.

[image: Imga]

**EDIT**

New feature request for microsoft was opened

[Feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1165014/add-unsynchronized-unbound-scrolling-option-in-sou.html)

**EDIT**

***In VS1029 Version 16.11.3 feature exist, by pressing it you can unbind the windows***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In compare option inside the source control, the scrolling is bind
> together for both files.

For this , I am afraid this is by designed. The same is true for my test in visual studio2019.

[image]

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Comment: Thank you, 
Feature request submitted https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1165014/add-unsynchronized-unbound-scrolling-option-in-sou.html